# Classnames not working as expected in React 16

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, classname

I want to apply this `classnames` object my input, in `react 16` project **without** `webpack` tool.

```
const fieldClassName = classnames(
      formControlStyles.field, 'form-control'
)
```

The form-control class is from bootstrap as you may notice.

And `.field` class is my class to override some attributes.

Please find below that `form-control` is overriding the `.field` class and I want the opposite to happen.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of time searching and asking, I found out that the normal stylesheet files must be placed on top of `index.js` file so that it would not conflicts with `classnames` managed styles

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with React, this depends upon how you write your css.
Eg:

```
.class1{
 color: red;
 // some property
}

.class2{
 color: green;
 // some property
}
```

And a div element

```
<div class="class1 class2"> Text </div>
```

Example here you wrote class2 after class1. It will take property of class2, so text will be displayed in green color.

```
    .class2{
      color: green;
      // some property
    }

   .class1{
      color: red;
      // some property
    }
```

And a div element

```
<div class="class1 class2"> Text </div>
```

Example here you wrote class1 after class2. It will take property of class1, so text will be displayed in red color.

Comment: I guess it is related to `css-loader` in React. As you may mention that the second class is generated

Comment: Yes it can be, you should include `form-control` class (Or I can say bootstrap) first then you can add your css files

Comment: I imported bootstrap in `index.js` like `import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'`

Comment: And how you include css for `formControlStyles.field` this class

Comment: Using Css modules of React (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)

Comment: For css modules you need to use classnames/bind